# Name of a list not the contents

Tags: r

I have a list containing 18 elements called `bx2`.

I want to use `bx2` in a function,

```
XlsMaker  <- function(x) {
  library("XLConnect")
a  <- length(x)
b  <- paste0(x,".xlsx")
for (i in 1:a){
writeWorksheetToFile(b, data = x[[i]], sheet = names(x[i]))
}
}
```

but when put I `bx2` into the function it pulls in all the elements of the list rather than just the name of the list.

Is it possible to re-write the function so that `b` becomes `bx2.xlsx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `b  <- paste0(x,".xlsx")` is wrong. That calls `paste0` on *the object `x` itself* which is not at all what you want to do. You want to call it on the *name* of the object.

This in general opens a can of worms because objects can have two different names in two different places. Consider: the object named `bx2` in your global environment is now named `x` within the function's scope. If you only want to call this function from the top level (e.g. for interactive use), you can safely get the name of the object from the parent environment (the environment you called the function from) by replacing that line with:

```
x_name <- deparse(substitute(x))
b <- paste0(x_name, ".xlsx")
```

The `substitute` function gets the name of `x` in the parent environment, as a special `name` object. The `deparse` function converts this `name` into a `character` vector of length one.

The reason I said this is only safe to use at the top level is that `substitute` can return surprising or unintended results if not used carefully. Hadley Wickham goes into detail on this point [in his book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#substitute).

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to deparse the parameter name

```
XlsMaker  <- function(x) {
    varname  <- deparse(substitute(x))
    library("XLConnect")
    a  <- length(x)
    b  <- paste0(varname ,".xlsx")
    for (i in 1:a){
        writeWorksheetToFile(b, data = x[[i]], sheet = names(x[i]))
    }
}
bx2 <-list(1:3, 4:6)
XlsMaker(bx2)
```